# Force download media

Tags: android, asp.net, download

I search from the internet and created this code to force download the media files.

```
            Stream stream = mi.GetMediaStream();
            long fileSize = stream.Length;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)fileSize];
            stream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)stream.Length);
            stream.Close();
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = String.Format(mi.MimeType);
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + mi.Name + "." + mi.Extension);
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
            Response.End();
```

It is working fine in desktop and Apple devices. But in android devices, it downloads and says that it is unsuccessful.

What seems to be the issue and how do I modify it?

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to the issue described here:
http://www.digiblog.de/2011/04/android-and-the-download-file-headers/

Maybe put the file name in quotes?

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + mi.Name + "." + mi.Extension + "\"");
```

Otherwise, if you're serving the file from a secure directory/site, it may be this bug:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1353

...in which case, the only thing you can really is star the issue and tell your users to use another browser on Android (not the default one, and not Chrome, because they both have the issue,as of this writing).

Good luck!